# Worklight WL.TabBar does not display correct titles on iOS

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-runtime

I downloaded the **IncludeExternalPages** project from the getting started site.  In the `main.js` for iPhone I can see what the `WL.TabBar` should display:

```
function wlEnvInit(){
    wlCommonInit();

    WL.TabBar.init();

    WL.TabBar.addItem("WLtab1", function () {tabClicked(1); } ,"Home",{
        image: "tabButton:Favorites"
    });

    WL.TabBar.addItem("WLtab2", function () {tabClicked(2); } ,"Client",{
        image: "tabButton:Search"
    });

    WL.TabBar.addItem("WLtab3", function () {tabClicked(3); } ,"IBM",{
        image: "tabButton:More"
    });

    WL.TabBar.setVisible(true);
    WL.TabBar.setSelectedItem("WLtab1");

    tabClicked(1); 
}
```

However, when executing this code in a simulator the labels are **Favorite**, **Search**, and **More** instead of **Home**, **Client**, and **IBM**.  I made no modifications to the project, just built it and ran on the iOS simulator.  This was using `WL6.2` with the 9/4 update (latest).

Any ideas why the titles are defaulting to iOS instead of what is specified in the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the "built-in" OS icons (Favorites, More, Search, ...) the tab item's title will default to that of the icon instead of the label in the code.

To change that, provide your own Favorites icon, for example, and then the "Home" label will be used.